# Unique filter on multiple criteria for a spill range

Tags: excel, filter, dynamic, unique

The following formula works only if I manually fill down the column.

```
'=(TEXTJOIN("| ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(rngNOTES,(rngDWG=$H3)*(rngASSY=$I3)*(rngASSY_DESCR=$J3)))))
```

In H3, I have a UNIQUE spill range of multiple rows and three columns. I am trying to make the above equation spill down the column rather than having to copy down the column. I have tried the following:

```
=(TEXTJOIN("| ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(rngNOTES,(rngDWG=INDEX($H3#,,1))*(rngASSY=INDEX($H3#,,2))*(rngASSY_DESCR=INDEX($H3#,,4))))))
```

But, I receive an error (#N/A), which I believe is a result of differences in the size (Row numbers) of the UNIQUE Spill in $H3# and the ranges I am trying to evaluate against.

Is there a method to make this work, such that the column containing this formula is dynamic?

---

EDIT:
[Screen Cap of Sample file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HitjX.jpg)

pgSystemTester, I have a sample file ready; located [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2W0bMiHBpnlEXqstURDG63GuXIvJObp/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110231881097256675177&rtpof=true&sd=true) on my Google Drive.

If I update K3 to

```
=IF(INDEX(H3#,,1)<>"",(TEXTJOIN("| ",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER(rngNOTES,(rngDWG=$H3)*(rngASSY=$I3)*(rngASSY_DESCR=$J3))))),"")
```

I can get the formula to spill. But the criteria references remain static and do not increment to the "new" row reference. The resulting data is correct for only ROW(1) and spills to the other rows as ROW(1) data.

[Updated results capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuWxw.jpg)

Which leads me to believe that I need to update the criteria in a way to reflect the new row location...this is where I am getting stuck.

Thank you,
Randy

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you an answer any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking for *free help* to solve *your problem*. Thanks.

Comment: Textjoin will never spill on its own (meaning the final calculation being done in a cell), since its sheer function is to JOIN an array. So at a minimum, you need another array formula to calculate AFTER the textjoin is complete.It would help if you provided a sample file or illustration that was simplified to a basic similar situation. Your named ranges make it hard to identify where the issue is.

Comment: Ken, Sorry for the shouting in the subject line. It was late and didn't even realize CAPS LOCK was on.

Comment: I edited to add a sample file using basic data. My end goal is to have the TEXTJOIN function expand/contract in response to data from the adjacent spill range containing the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @pgSystemTester's comment, Textjoin won't spill on it's own as it's made to return a single result for whole arrays (in this case the array `H3#`).
To overcome this, you need to split your spilling array into rows, and apply the textjoin function to each row individually. Making the formula for a single row and manually copying it down is one option for this, but to spill it dynamically you can use the `BYROW()` function which is created to solve this exact problem.

```
=BYROW(H3#,LAMBDA(row,TEXTJOIN("|", TRUE, UNIQUE(FILTER(rngNOTES,(rngDWG=INDEX(row,1))*(rngASSY=INDEX(row,2))*(rngASSY_DESCR=INDEX(row,3)))))))
```

Note how I had to use `INDEX(row, x)` in the filters because it can't take separate arrays H3#, I3# and J3# (plus, H3# spans all three columns so the `row` array does as well).